# Let AB be a fixed line segment. Let P be a moving point such that angle APB is equal to a constant acute angle. Then point P moves along which curve?

Tags: analytic-geometry

Answer is: The boundary of union of two identical intersecting circles with centers outside the common region.

Comment: What is your question? How to prove this? In that case, what have you tried?

Comment: I don't know how to initialize this. I tried getting some idea by drawing the figure. But no use.

Comment: Please use the body of the Question to give a full statement of the problem you want help with, including the context of why this problem is interesting or challenging for you.  Stuffing the problem statement into the title alone may seem expeditious, but it invites confusion for Readers and relies on them to guess at what help is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P, P'$ be two such points. If $APP'B$ is cyclic, the $P'$ lies on the circumcircle of $\triangle APB$. Otherwise, the reflection of $P'$ across $\overline{AB}$, $P^*$, makes cyclic quadrilateral $APP^*B$, so $P'$ lies on the reflection of the circle across $AB$.